# Does the quaternion that Eigen extracts from an Affine3d 3x3 rotation matrix is normalized?

Tags: c++, eigen, ros, quaternions, homogenous-transformation

here https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/eigen_conversions/html/eigen__msg_8cpp_source.html#l00093

I quite do not understand the syntax of this line : `Eigen::Quaterniond q = (Eigen::Quaterniond)e.linear();`

But anyway, assuming `e` is of type `Eigen::Affine3d` (3x3 rotation matrix), **where can I figure out how a quaternion is constructed fron a rotation matrix in Eigen library** please? I did not saw any method on the doc, except https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1QuaternionBase.html#title25 but I'm a real noob in c++ so I do not even understand that one...

I hope it does something like this https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/2.4654?journalCode=jgcd because my need is that the extracted quaternion must be normalized, and I would like to ensure this.

Comment: The actual implementation is [here](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/5e026965630ede13841796f/Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h#Quaternion.h-779), which includes a reference to the underlying algorithm. The code will generate unit-quaternions as long as the input matrix is actually a rotation matrix (everything subject to noise, of course).

Comment: The `(Eigen::Quaterniond)` cast is not necessary, btw.

Comment: Note, you shold hold rotation matrix orthonormal and quaternion normalized itself, in case with lot of transformations of single entity (camera for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that your `Eigen::Quaterniond` is normalised by calling it's `normalize()` method.

The line in question is explicitly converting whatever `e.linear()` returns to a `Eigen::Quaterniond`.

As to how you go from a rotation matrix to a quaternion, [Wikipedia describes the relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation). It's just solving a known set of simultaneous equations. I expect the body of the method to look (more or less) like a bunch of algebra.

Comment: Thanks Sir, the thing is I'm not confident/qualified enough for temporarily modify https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/eigen_conversions/html/eigen__msg_8cpp_source.html#l00093 to print the norm of the constructed quaternion, that is why I'd like to ensure it by reading the source only.
Also the paper I gave the link of comes from Wikipedia references, but unfortunately this bunch of algebra isn't in the URL you gave https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#From_an_orthogonal_matrix_to_a_quaternion and one has to look into the paper via some unlocking 3rd-party websites.

Comment: If you are not confident in your understanding of C++, then you most likely won't be able to determine *by looking at source* if the Eigen implementation is correct. I would instead go looking for [test methods](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tests) that demonstrate the properties that you care about